# Change raster extent

Tags: r, raster, extent

I have global shortwave radiation data. I will like to change the extent to lon and lat. The current extent is in the form below:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 7200, 3600, 25920000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0.5, 3600.5, 0.5, 7200.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : /Users/gogunkoya/Documents/PATAGONIA/RAW_DATA_ARCHIVE/BESS_RadData/BESS_RSDN_Monthly.A201201.nc 
names       : surface_downwelling_shortwave_flux_in_air 
zvar        : surface_downwelling_shortwave_flux_in_air
```

I have tried to change the extent by using the raster  extent function:

```
bb <- extent(-180,180,-90,90)
extent(r) <- bb
```

I also want to rotate the map to be horizontal.

[image: Map of global short wave radiation]

Answer (score 1):

Using `t` worked for me.

```
library(raster)

xy <- matrix(sample(1:10, size = 3*5, replace = TRUE), nrow = 3)
xy <- raster(xy)
xy

extent(xy) <- extent(c(-2, 2, -2, 2))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(xy)
plot(t(xy))
```